# Is CV inflated when mean and standard deviation are negatively correlated?

Tags: regression, correlation, standard-deviation, autocorrelation, coefficient-of-variation

I have two **quantitative traits** coming from 145 individuals x 12 environments combination. My goal is to correlate the specialization of each individual (trait 1) to the mean of each individual across 12 environments (trait 2).

Both traits are positively correlated. To measure specialization, I estimated the coefficient of variation for each individual. Then I correlated this specialization index of trait 1 with the mean for trait 2 for each individual and vice versa.

Now, in trait 1, mean and standard deviation are positively correlated, but in trait 2, both are negatively correlated. However, both correlation here has valid biological explanation due to the nature of the trait.

My questions are when the mean and SD have different correlations on different traits, is it valid to correlate the CV of one trait with the mean of the other trait? Of course, the relationship gives a valid biological explanation.

But there is an artifact due to the statistical autocorrelation. How can I separate the biological value from the statistical autocorrelation? Is there any reference where I can find some descriptions and ways to make an argument? I do not want to alter the relationships but to argue with some good reasonings.

Comment: Can you define CV here? Cross validation? Coefficient of variation? Something else?

Comment: I can't follow this easily. To pick up the most puzzling detail first, autocorrelation usually refers to dependence in time or space. You appear to mean something quite different, namely some kind of inbuilt relationship. To pick up a common point next, coefficient of variation can be helpful if and only is SD is (roughly) proportional to the mean. A negative correlation between SD and mean is just about the least likely circumstance for CV to be helpful. If I understand this correctly you are looking at 12 means and 12 SDs for 2 traits. Can you show those here, graphically and/or in a table?

Comment: Hi, so CV is the coefficient of variation estimated from the mean and SD. I have 145 mean values for 2 traits for 145 individuals across 12 environments. So, I used CV as a measure of the degree of specialization to a particular environment. The problem is, mean and SD are positively and negatively correlated in trait 1 and trait 2, respectively. Moreover, the correlation of mean values between the two traits is positive. Until that point is fine. But then I used the specialization (i.e. CV) to correlate with the mean of each trait (e.g. CV of trait 1 VS mean of trait 2, vice-versa).

Comment: In all the cases the sample size is 145 individuals. The problem is arising as there is a statistical phenomenon (positive and negative correlation between mean and SD in two traits), how can I argue that between the statistical artifact and biological phenomenon? Because the relationship make every sense in terms of biology. I guess CV is useful when mean and SD are increasing positively, am I right or wrong here?

Comment: For trait 2, where mean and SD are positively correlated, the correlation between the CV of trait 2 and mean of trait 1 is OK. But in the case of trait 1, where the mean and SD is negatively correlated, estimation of CV, in that case, is inflated or not? The data used to do all the analyses are log-transformed.

Comment: Is there any way that I keep my estimates of CV considering the statistical artifactual issues? Is there any reference paper showing an argument like this? Please help. I am trying to answer a reviewer for my paper and the deadline is approaching.