# Is estimation of Coefficient of variation (CV) misleading when sample mean and standard deviation is negatively correlated?

Tags: correlation, mean, standard-deviation, multicollinearity, coefficient-of-variation

I have a dataset with 145 individuals and two traits measured in 12 environments. I want to measure the variation among individuals i.e. individuals with high performance in one environment and low performance in others would have higher CV. I know that CV is useful when mean and SD are positively correlated.
But when they are negatively correlated, how does this affect the estimation of CV? Is it misleading to estimate CV in such scenarios? Is there any reference or explanations for this kind of issues?
Thank you.

Comment: Repetition of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470547/is-cv-inflated-when-mean-and-standard-deviation-are-negatively-correlated I think you didn't get an answer previously because "misleading" could mean so many different things and everything hinges on what you do with these coefficients of variation once they are calculated. As I am not clear that CVs could be useful in this circumstance, one guess is that they are not helpful. But I doubt there are references discussing this.

Comment: Hi, so I am using CV as a measure of degree of specialization to a particular environment. When some individuals are specialized to a specific environment for higher trait performance, their overall performance across different environments is low compared to those who follow a generalist strategy (i.e. consistent performance across environments). It is well known to use CV for capturing such variability for continuous data. As CV is estimated from mean and SD, how the negative relationship between mean and SD affect the CV estimation, is my question. I could not find any reference.

Comment: If by *negative relationship* you intend to suggest that there is a negative mean value (less than zero) then, yes, the CV is *misleading* and even useless. It's only defined when the inputs are greater than zero. There are lots of other metrics that could be substituted, e.g., Gini Coefficient, Shannon entropy, Akaike's Information Criterion, etc.

Comment: No, by negative correlation I do not mean that mean values are less than zero. The trend is when mean increases the SD decreases because individuals perform consistently across the environment. There is no negative value. Shannon entropy works for discrete data but mine is quantitative data. When I correlated individual's CV with their overall mean, I get a negative correlation, that is fine. But there is also negative correlation between mean and SD which is generating the issue of autocorrelation. That is the problem and I do not know what to do to be honest.

Comment: Ok...actually, Shannon entropy can also be used with your data. So, are you saying that you have 13 means and std devs for each individual for each environment and that, by correlating those 13 values, you get negative correlations? This is confusing. I've thought about the use of the CV for quite a while and have never read anything about evaluating it vis-a-vis correlations. As noted, it's use is only contraindicated when the mean value is negative. If you're still uncertain, why not back it up with more  uncertainty/specialization metrics, i.e., why rely on just one?

Comment: Hi, I have measured a trait in 145 individuals in 12 different environments. After a combined ANOVA, I got 145 mean and SD across all environments. Then I correlated 145 mean and SD which showed a strong negative correlation. Considering my experiment, this has a clear biological explanation. Many individuals gave consistent performance in all environments which increased their overall mean while reducing the variation. So a negative correlation. But my question is how can I separate or account for this inherent autocorrelation while doing Pearson correlation between CV and the overall mean.

Comment: How does *consistent performance* result in increasing/decreasing metric values? Seems contradictory. I would offer a different interpretation: participants demonstrated an ability to *learn* as the study unfolded across environments as demonstrated by increasing mean values and decreasing SDs. I can think of no way to control for autocorrelation using a Pearson correlation. It's a pairwise metric of linear dependence *only*. You need to step into a time series modeling protocol to control for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Well, if some individuals show high performance e.g. yield of 2-3 kg in each of the 10 environments, then there combined mean is high whereas the SD is low due to more or less similar performance. Isn't it the case? Yes, I though about Autoregression models using GLS. But then can I report correlation coefficient? or even an R-squared value? I do not know about this. Besides, is my data suitable for time series modeling as the data were collected on a single time? I do not follow how can I put my data in a time series frame. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A couple of things. First, *autocorrelation* is a term reserved for time series data only. Second, based on your experimental design chronology is expressed in the sequence of information gathered, not by the clock. This approach lends itself to a time series format. Assuming those sequences were randomized across participants you could test for independent effects by environment. Finally, this methodology lends itself to metric estimates of association and dependence.

Comment: Hi, I seem to disagree with the statement that my data falls in the time series. So I have collected all the data from 12 environments on the same day. I have not fully understood what you meant by "this methodology lends itself to metric estimates of association and dependence". Can you please explain this?

Comment: My question is did your 145 participants respond in all 12 environments at the same time? Or did they respond in a sequence, from one environment to the next? If the latter, that sequence is implicitly temporal.

Comment: No, they responded at the same time in all 12 environments.

Comment: Autocorrelation makes perfect sense for spatial data; there is an entire book with that title alone. But I agree that it's the wrong term here, as I pointed out in the earlier thread. Sorry, but I remain unclear on the much bigger issue of what kind of answer you seek.